# Proving a function of a random variable is greater than some value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let X be a positive random variable with E(X) = 1. Prove E[X log X] ≥ 0.

I think I need to use Jensen's inequality but I'm not too sure.

I know X is positive so P(X > 0) = 1.

$$g(x) = xlog(x)$$

$$g'(x) = log(x) + 1$$

$$g''(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$$

Since the second derivative is greater than 0 for all possible values of X, g(X) must be convex. Therefore, using Jensen's inequality I can say:

$$E(g(x)) = E(xlog(x)) >= g(E(X)) = 1*log(1) = 0$$

Am I proving this correctly?

Comment: That looks fine

Comment: That's correct.